# Are Besov spaces $B^{s}_{p,q}$ invariant under Fourier transform?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

(This may be very easy question for MO; as I am just trying to understand Besov spaces)

Let $\phi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^{n})$ with 
$ \operatorname{supp} \phi \subset \{\xi \in \mathbb R^{n}: |\xi|\leq 2\} , \phi(\xi)=1$ if $|\xi|\leq 1.$
We put,
$$\phi_{j}(\xi)= \phi(2^{-j}\xi)- \phi(2^{-j+1}\xi),  (\xi \in \mathbb R^{n}, j \in \mathbb N).$$
Then we have 
$$\operatorname{supp} \phi_{j} \subset \{\xi\in \mathbb R^{n}: 2^{j-1}\leq |\xi| \leq 2^{j+1} \},  j\in \mathbb N $$
and, with $\phi_{0}=\phi,$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi_{k}(\xi)=1, \text{if} \ \xi\in \mathbb R^{n}.$$

Perhaps there  different ways to introduce [Besov spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besov_space); we define in the following way.

Let $0<p\leq \infty, 0 <q \leq \infty$ and $s\in \mathbb R$ then 
$$B^{s}_{p,q}(\mathbb R^{n})=\{f\in \mathcal{S'}(\mathbb R^{n}):\|f\|_{B^{s}_{p,q}}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{ksq} \|(\phi_{k}\hat{f})^{\vee}\|_{L^{p}}^{q}\right)^{1/q}<\infty \}.$$

Examples. $B^{s}_{2,2}(\mathbb R^{n})= H^{s}(\mathbb R^{n})(=\text{Sobolev spaces}).$

**My naive questions are**:

> (1) Is $B^{0}_{1,1}(\mathbb R^{n})$ can be embedded in $L^{1}(\mathbb R^{n})$ ? (or other $L^{p}$ for $1\leq p \leq \infty$)
>   (2) Is $B^{0}_{1,1}(\mathbb R^{n})$ is invariant under Fourier transform, that is, if $f\in B^{0}_{1,1}(\mathbb R^{n}),$ then $\hat{f} \in B^{0}_{1,1}(\mathbb R^{n})$ ? (3) What about $B^{s}_{p,q}(\mathbb R^{n})$ except for $p=q=2$ ? (4) What does this definition tells us intuitively ? (5) Is there some thing special about dyadic decompositions ?

Thanks,

Comment: I know that the Fourier transform of a function in a modulation space is at least again in a modulation space. Depending a bit on their definition, the usual 3 parameter definition should be invariant?! I think for $p=q$.

Comment: What do you mean by "(5) Is there some thing special about dyadic decompositions?" Since some Besov spaces can be embedded in modulation spaces you could write their norms with frequency uniform decompositions. Like $B^s_{2,2} = M_{2,2}^s$ coincides with $H^{s}$ so it is characterizable by dyadic or frequency uniform decompositions.

Comment: @CPJ; Thanks, but $M^{1,1}\subset B^{0}_{1,1}$; so I don't know how does it help here ?; thanks

Comment: As I said I don't know whether or not the Fourier pictures of Besov spaces are Besov spaces; I think in genral it is not the case. (I think the reason for the introduction of modulation spaces was exactly this question to find Fourier-invariant spaces. http://www.univie.ac.at/nuhag-php/bibtex/open_files/fe06-1_feifinalstsip.pdf)

Comment: I think Besov spaces do not contain spaces that are invariant under the Fourier transform. That is at least what Feichtinger says in http://www.univie.ac.at/nuhag-php/bibtex/open_files/fe83-1_mod-kiev.pdf and I sort of trust him on this. See page 5.

Comment: @CPJ;thanks; but still I wonder how is that true ? (Because bit  roughly speaking, dyadic decomposition operators combined with function
spaces $\ell^{q}(L^{p})$ generate Besov spaces, frequency-uniform decomposition operators
joint with function spaces $\ell^{q}(L^{p})$ produce modulation spaces. ) I have been trying to seek the underneath crucial point..; thanks

Comment: @CPJ; your link is indeed useful; thanks

Answer (score 6):

Let me note $\phi_k(D)$ the Fourier multiplier $\phi_k(\xi)$, i.e.
$
\text{Fourier}\bigl(\phi_k(D)u\bigr)(\xi)=\phi_k(\xi)\hat u(\xi).
$

$\bullet$ The answer to (1) is yes since
$$
\Vert{u}\Vert_{L^1}=\Vert{\sum_{k\ge 0}\phi_k(D)u}\Vert_{L^1}\le
\sum_{k\ge 0}\Vert{\phi_k(D)u}\Vert_{L^1} =\Vert{u}\Vert_{B^0_{1,1}}.
$$

$\bullet$ The answer to (2) is no: take $u=\sum_{k\ge 1} a_k\hat \phi(2^{k}x)2^{kn}$ with $a_k\ge 0$ and  $\phi$ a smooth  function in $\mathbb R^n$ with support the ring
$\{\frac12\le \vert \xi\vert\le 2\}$.
We have 
$$
((\text{Fourier}(\phi_k(D) u))(\xi)=a_k\phi(\xi 2^{-k})^2,\quad \phi_k(D) u(x)=a_k
\widehat{\phi^2}(2^{k}x)2^{kn},\quad \Vert u\Vert_{B^0_{1,1}}=\Vert\widehat{\phi^2}\Vert_{L^1}\sum_{k\ge 1}a_k.
$$
On the other hand, we have
$
\hat u(\xi)=\sum_{k\ge 1}a_k\phi(\xi/2^k
)$
and since the dyadic rings $C_k, C_{k+2}$
are disjoint, assuming $a_k=0$ for $k$ odd, we get with $c>0$
$$
\Vert \hat u\Vert_{L^1}\ge c\sum_{l\ge 1}a_{2l} 2^{2ln}.
$$
Choosing
$
a_{2l}=2^{-2ln}
$
we find that $u\in B^0_{1,1}$ and $\hat u\notin L^1$, which implies from (1)
that 
$\hat u\notin B^0_{1,1}$.

Comment: thanks; would you please tell me, why $\|u\|_{L^{1}}= \|\sum_{k\geq 0}\phi_{k}(D)u\|_{L^{1}}$?(I guess, I need to use $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\phi_{k}(\xi)=1$ but I don,t know how); thanks

Comment: The equality $\sum_{k\ge 0}\phi_k(\xi)=1$ is equivalent to $\sum_{k\ge 0}\phi_k(D)=Id.$